# Doctest error al intentar capturar Exception Value error

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

Os reporto un error de testing. Intento capturar el error de introducir un valor negativo en una raíz cuadrada.

Mi código:

```
import math 

def listaraicescuadradas(Listanumeros):
    """ 
    la funcion devuelve una lista con la raiz cuadrada
    de los elementos pasados en otra lista por argumentos.
    >>> lista = []
    >>> for i in [4, -9, 16]:
    ... lista.append(i)
    >>> listaraicescuadradas(lista)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: math domain error


    """
    return [math.sqrt(n) for n in Listanumeros ]

import doctest

doctest.testmod()
```

El error que me dispara es:

```
ValueError: line 12 of the docstring for __main__.listaraicescuadradas has inconsistent leading whitespace: 'ValueError: math domain error
```

Gracias adelantadas.

Answer (score 0):

Chicos, al copiar el error me he dado cuenta de que no he leído bien el mensaje. 
Mi error es de espacios inconsistentes. La verdad es que no se cuales son esos espacios que daban problemas pero he borrado todos los espacios entre los diferentes doctest, e tabulado correctamente en caso de que hubiera alguno por ahí, y ahora me funciona.

Si es necesario borrar mi pregunta, lo haré. perdonen mis torpezas.